# Are the contents of highlighted content saved to a register

Tags: vimscript, search

Let me briefly explain what I am trying to do.  I work on an air gap network.  Anything not native to Red hat, or that I do not write is out of the question.  The most popular two IDE's are VIM/GVIM and Eclipse.

For many of us, there is only one reason to go into eclipse, the indexer.  The code base we work on is quite large.  The configuration I work in alone is over a terabyte when compiled. Currently I am using a combination of grep and find to locate files and information in them.  It doesn't seem like it should be hard to to write an external indexing deamon, but in order to be useful it would nice to be able to easily interface with a string.  I guess I could just copy it to something but I figured I'd check and see if there was some hidden register somewhere that was already doing what I wanted.

Comment: middle click in X?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the X copy paste buffer, but I was hoping I could integrate with the find feature, using *.

Comment: What's your desired workflow?

Comment: Uh, tags generator? À la exuberant or universal ctags? Vim has built in support for navigation via these: see `help tags`

Comment: When I highlight a string with *, I can use n to find it in the file. I want to be able to hit another key combination to launch a script or external program with that as the argument

Answer (score 1):

The highlight <kbd>*</kbd> is actually just a search for word nearest to current cursor. So they are available in ‘last search pattern register’ `/` (that is slash register).

If you don’t want the word boundary `\<` and `\>`, use <kbd>g*</kbd> instead.

In case you highlighting (selecting) using Vim visual-mode or mouse selection, you can press <kbd>y</kbd> afterward. This will make it available in unnamed register `”` (a double-quote). And if you want it in other register, just prepend double-quote and the register name before <kbd>y</kbd>. For example <kbd>“sy</kbd> will make it available in register `s`.

Comment: In vimscript, that register’s contents are in `@/`